# If $f$ is a continuous function, find $f(2)$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find $f(2)$ if $$\int_0^{x^2} f(t) \, dt = x^2(1+x) +C$$

In case of integration from $0$ to $x$ I got the answer just by differentiating with respect to $x$ (FTC). However, I am stuck with the differentiation with respect to $x^2$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{0}^{x^2}f(t)dt\right)=f(x)\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)-0=2xf(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and the Chain Rule we have $$\frac{d}{dx} \left[\int_0^{x^2} f(t)dt \right]=f(x)\cdot [x^2]'=2xf(x).$$ On the other hand $$\frac{d}{dx}[x^2(1+x)+C]=[2x(1+x)+x^2]+0=2x+2x^2+x^2=3x^2+2x.$$ and thus $2xf(x)=3x^2+2x$, by hipothesis. Assuming $x \neq 0$: $$2xf(x)=3x^2+2x \Leftrightarrow f(x)=\frac{3x^2+2x}{2x}=\frac{3}{2}x+1.$$ Hence $f(2)=\dfrac{3}{2}(2)+1=3+1=4$.

Comment: I tried to intigrate the expression with respect to $x^2$ by imagining $x^3$ as ((x^2)^3/2) and I got $1+3x^2/2$ but the answer is $1+3sqrt(x)/2$

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate both sides of the equality. First, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x^2} f(t)dt = f(x) \cdot (x^2)’=2xf(x).$$
On the other hand $$\frac{d}{dx}[x^2(x+1)+C = 3x^2+2x.$$ So we have $$2xf(x)=3x^2+2x \implies f(x)=\frac{3x}{2}+1.$$ This formula for $f$ doesn’t apply if $x =0$.